# Point multi domain on Ajenti Panel

Tags: hosting, panel, vps

I needing a panel on linux run my wwebsite. I have installed Ajenti Panel (ajenti.org) but i only run a domain on master. I want point multi domain in this panel. I have install plugin:

```
Apache 2, php (all), mysql-server, Bind9....
```

How to step by step point second domain on Ajenti .

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Go to configurations and under http server setup host to your VM ip. Now it should be available under any of your domains.

Recommendatio:
Install ajenti v. Here is how install it on debian http://support.ajenti.org/topic/353398-installing-ajenti-v-on-debian/